# SQL convert rows to one Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table,

Output before pivoting:

```
keli |  onoma
-----+---------------
name |  Step1
a1   |  DSP
a2   |  Tekmiriosi
```

Expected output:

```
Step1 | DSP | Tekmiriosi
```

How to do that for three or more rows but always with to one-row column?

Comment: `three or more rows` ... so you basically want to collapse the entire table into a single row?  Something else?

Comment: Try to use crosstab function

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to concatenate all values? Use `STRING_AGG`, eg `select string_agg(oonoma, ' | ') from thatTable`. Or convert rows to columns? That's called pivoting,

Comment: BTW using Greeklish in field names or values is a very, *very* bad idea. All databases support Unicode strings, so there's no reason *at all* to store Greeklish values. Table and field names should be easy to read too, and Greeklish names are hard to read even for Greeks

Comment: This is nothing new either. Windows is a Unicode OS, so once it replaced DOS even in POS systems in the late 1990s-2000, there was no longer any need for Greeklish or even ASCII codepages. Some accounting packages kept using DOS/Unix with 8-bit text for a while, until they either went out of business or the vendors were forced to create completely new applications or go out of business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(onoma) filter (where keli = 'name'),
       max(onoma) filter (where keli = 'a1'),
       max(onoma) filter (where keli = 'a2')
from t;
```

However, I might suggest that you if you want all values in a single row that you just use arrays:

```
select array_agg(keli)
from t;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use following query

```
create table temp
(
    keli  varchar(100),
    onoma varchar(100)
)

insert into temp values ('name', 'Step1')
insert into temp values ('a1', 'DSP')
insert into temp values ('a2', 'Tekmiriosi')

DECLARE @column AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @qry AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @column = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.onoma) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @qry = 'SELECT ' + @column + ' from 
            (
                select onoma
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(onoma)
                for onoma in (' + @column + ')
            ) p '

execute(@qry)
drop table temp
```